# Angularjs dosent work on ios phonegap app

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, phonegap, ios9.3

Hello i build a phonegap app for android and ios and its works ok on android phones an iphones with ios v.10+ works grate. But on older version and specific on ipad 2 with ios v9.3.5 angularjs doesn't work. I tried to load angular.min.js from google cdn and after from a local and nothing changed. I find in many site to add this line and it nothing affected.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap: file:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

what can be a problem?

[The screenshot off app on iPad 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOQ0n.png)

Comment: Can you see any error or warning when you open the browser console?

Comment: browser console on ipad? on desktop test all clean.

Comment: Try to open the `.xcodeproj` file inside Xcode. Its console should show what's the error.